# Get id in jQuery and use it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I generate with a loop for every section on my html site a [list element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgr5L.png).

```
<section class="page1" id="name1"></section>
<section class="page2" id="name2"></section>
<section class="page3" id="name3"></section>`
```

In my jQuery function, see below, I create for every section a link.

```
for( var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
  _addClass(sections[i], "ops-section")
  sections[i].dataset.index = i + 1;
  sections[i].id=document.getElementById(sections[i].id);
   if(settings.pagination == true) {
         paginationList += '<li><a data-index="' 
     + (i + 1) + '" href="#' + (i + 1) 
     + '"></a><p class="lead">' 
     + sections[i].id + '</p></li>';
    }
```

with `sections[i].id=document.getElementById(sections[i].id);` I want to read out the text behind id, for example: name1. name2, name3 and so on. I want to add the id-name then as text between the p-tag, so that I get the following list element:

```
<li><a data-index="1" href="#1" class="active"></a><p class="lead">name1</p></li>
```

but actually I get this:

```
<li><a data-index="1" href="#1" class="active"></a><p class="lead">[object HTMLElement]</p></li>
```

Where is my mistake? What's wrong?

Comment: You already have the id, why do you try to get the element behind it? try simply removing `sections[i].id=document.getElementById(sections[i].id)`

Comment: Because you're still adding a _whole_ HTML element into the `id` attribute of that element. This came up in the same question you asked earlier today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are going about this the wrong way and making the code harder to follow in the process. Your issue is that you are concatenating an entire DOM node, rather than a value of one of the attributes of that node because of this line:

```
sections[i].id = document.getElementById(sections[i].id)
```

`.getElementById()` returns a DOM node so later, when you use:

```
sections[i].id
```

You aren't referring to the `id` at all, you are referring to the entire element returned from:

```
document.getElementById(sections[i].id)
```

You don't really even need any of that entire line anyway.

If you use a `.forEach()` loop to enumerate the `section` elements, you won't have to set up or manage a counter.

If you create the elements via the DOM API (instead of building a string), you can configure each element much more simply and get out of concatenation hell.

Look at the solution below, it's a little more overall code than your solution, but it is so much cleaner and easier to follow.

```js
// Get the section elements into an array
var theSections = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("section[class^='page']"));

// Loop over the elements in the array
theSections.forEach(function(section, index){
  // Create li, a and p elements
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  
  // Configure each new element
  a.setAttribute("data-index", index + 1);
  a.href = index + 1;
  a.classList.add("active");
  p.classList.add("lead");
  p.textContent = section.id;
  
  // Inject new elements into the DOM
  li.appendChild(a);
  li.appendChild(p);
  document.body.appendChild(li); 
  
  // Just for testing
  console.log(a, p);
});
```

```html
<section class="page1" id="name1"></section>
<section class="page2" id="name2"></section>
<section class="page3" id="name3"></section>
```

Comment: You can also use `.forEach()` on a `NodeList`, so you don't need `Array.prototype.slice.call`.

Comment: @Synch Not all browsers implement `.forEach()` on node lists (no version of IE does) yet, so you need the explicit conversion for the time being.

Comment: Ah, I see. You're right, thanks for the heads-up. Though in all honesty, you deserve broken web pages if you are using IE or Edge.

Comment: @Synch There are millions of proprietary "in-house" applications that were built to run on some version of IE during the early 2000's. Those applications aren't going anywhere and corporate developers have no choice but to write code that works in it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why is it not working?

First, `document.getElementById` retrieves an HTML element. Then, you are overriding the id in `sections[i].id` with the HTML element, resulting in `[object HTMLElement]`.

#### Solution

As suggested by Liora Haydont, simply remove the line `sections[i].id=document.getElementById(sections[i].id);`.

```
for( var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
  _addClass(sections[i], "ops-section")
  sections[i].dataset.index = i + 1;
   if(settings.pagination == true) {
         paginationList += '<li><a data-index="' 
     + (i + 1) + '" href="#' + (i + 1) 
     + '"></a><p class="lead">' 
     + sections[i].id + '</p></li>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're attaching an entire HTML element to the section id which is why you're getting that error. Scott just beat me with his answer, but I'm in agreement with him. Using `forEach` will allow you to make your life a little easier.

In this example I'm also using template literals to create the HTML. YMMV, however.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const out = document.getElementById('out');

const settings = {
  pagination: true
}

sections.forEach((section, i) => {
  const index = i + 1;
  const id = section.id;
  section.classList.add('ops-section');
  section.dataset.index = index;
  if (settings.pagination) {
    const para = `<p class="lead">${id}</p>`;
    const li = `<li><a data-index="${index}" href="#${index}" class="active">test</a>${para}</li>`;
    out.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', li);
  }
});
```

```html
<section class="page1" id="name1">section1</section>
<section class="page2" id="name2">section2</section>
<section class="page3" id="name3">section3</section>

<ul id="out"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using JQuery ? This is a small demo on how you can get the `id` attribute of your section and use it in the JQuery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('section').each(function( key, value ) {
    // alert($(this).attr('id') + " - " +  key + ": " + value );
    $('pagination').append("<p class='lead'>* <a data-index='"+ key +"' href=#></a>" + $(this).attr('id') + '</p>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="page1" id="name1"></section>
<section class="page2" id="name2"></section>
<section class="page3" id="name3"></section>

<pagination></pagination>
```

Comment: *Why not using JQuery?* Because it's overkill for such a simple operation that can be handled without it? JQuery is widely overused. When it was introduced, it made many tedious jobs much simpler. But, since then, the DOM API has matured and we have just as simple ways of solving many problems without JQuery. Use JQuery to make complex tasks easier. Don't use it to make easy jobs easy.

Comment: I agree with you, but Jeremia seems to have it as he writes: ...`In my j!Qery function`... so as it's already here, let's use it.

Comment: Or, let's get rid of extra bloat that we don't need so we can see the problem clearly and solve it cleanly.